# symmetric $(v,k,\lambda)$-design

Tags: combinatorial-designs

I need help to **prove the lemma**, knowing the following corollary about the symmetric $(v,k,\lambda)$-designs.

**Corollary.** Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
 A(i,j)
 \end{bmatrix}$ be the associated matrix of some  $(v,k,\lambda)$-design symmetric. Then,

1. $ A^TA =(k-\lambda)I_v+\lambda J_v;$
2. $AA^T =(k-\lambda)I_v+\lambda J_v;$
3. $J_vA=kJ_v;$
4. $AJ_v=kJ_v.$

**Lemma.** Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
 A(i,j)
 \end{bmatrix}$  be a $\{0,1\}$-valued non-singular matrix of order $v$. Then, Equation $1.$  is true iff Equation $2.$ is true. Moreovoer, the $A$ is an associate matrix of some $(v,k,\lambda)$-design symmetric iff $1.$ (or $2.$) is satisfied.

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that $A$ commutes with $A^T$. If 1 holds,
$A^T=(k-\lambda)A^{-1}+A^{-1}J$. As $A$ commutes with $A^{-1}$
and with $J$, it commutes with $A^{-1}J$ and so with $A^T$.